# Configuring Webpack for Manually Added Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, npm, webpack

Simple question about jquery and webpack,

I have downloaded `jquery.js` then added into `app.js` these lines

```
import "./jquery";
import "./bootstrap";
```

My `webpack.config` entry line

```
entry: "./src/app.js"
```

So files tree is:

```
./webpack.config.js
./src/app.js
./src/jquery.js
./src/bootstrap.js
```

How can I simply add `jquery` to define in `webpack.config` with this file tree while it is functional?

I tried adding

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
```

at the end of the `webpack.config` but it gives `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery'`.

What is the solution for using js files manually with webpack for bundling without an error?

Comment: Did you add the `jquery` package with either npm or yarn? You won't have to download it manually if you are using the npm package, and it should allow you to use it with webpack

Comment: @TFischer I downloaded js file and put it next to app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1 :**

In general, Webpack is a module bundler.

It allows bundling your own modules (`require("./my-module.js")`) as well as thirdparty modules (`require("bootstrap")`)

In your case, that would mean you dont have to download the jquery and bootstrap files yourself. Update your `package.json` to include the required jquery and bootstrap modules. NPM will take care of getting them and webpack will do the bundling from the `node_modules` files.

**Step 2 :**

In general, webpack needs and `entry` point and `output` locations. Thats the minimal config it needs.

Once you have an `entry` point, webpack still needs to know what dependencies your code needs. Be it your own modules or thirdparty modules (maintained with npm). That is where the `require("module-name-or-path")` or `import "module-name-or-path"` comes into picture. What that means is that you need to make sure your `entry` script has all the required dependencies mentioned either in the same file or in the dependent modules.

To give more insight, webpack looks at the `entry` point and will build the dependency graph. It will read all that `require()` or `import` and pulls in all required modules. It then bundles it.

In your case, the entry script can include the `require` statements for jquery and bootstrap npm modules (i.e. thirdparty)

In case, you still need clarity, feel free to go through the code [here](https://github.com/rakcheru/webpack-bootstrap/tree/v1.0/). Especially take a look at `src/entry.js`

Note : Bootstrap needs fonts and images as well. The code in repository above, takes care of them too. All the magic done by `webpack`!

Comment: Thank you for this informative detailed answer. However I think yet `webpack` also can take care of manually downloaded js files. Take my `jquery.js` as a `different js` file I wrote myself and I need to `bundle it` while bundle js can understand `$` and `jquery` terms. There must be a solution for this.

Comment: @hello_stack There is! You can use `require("script-loader!./jquery.js")` . You can get more information about script loader : https://webpack.js.org/loaders/script-loader . However, i do strongly encourage you to go with npm's downloaded module files. Otherwise you will have to take care of all the required files yourself. Take for ex: webpack needs font and image files. You need to make sure you download them too **and** webpack is able to use them while bundling your downloaded bootstrap code. The less you work directly with thirdparty module source files the better. Let webpack take care.

Comment: Script-loader is a good solution for this problem. But I don't understand something. If I wrote another js file, I can import it in app.js and it is working without any problem. Now why can't we import jqeury without any problem and without any additional loader? Thanks

Comment: Thats because the `ProvidePlugin` only takes a module name (as string) and internally tries to load the same using `require()`. For you to use jquery in your code, it needs to be exposed as global. Obviously `ProvidePlugin` wont help you with **downloaded** code. You have two options : 1. Expose the jquery yourself as global variable 2. As mentioned earlier, use jquery as module. Hope that helps.